# What is the degree of $(y')^2-2xy'+x^2=0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

What is the degree of $(y')^2-2xy'+x^2=0$ ? Is it two or we should say the equation is equivalent to,
$(y'-x)^2=0\Rightarrow y'=x$
And the degree is one ?

Comment: It is a first-order non-linear equation.

Comment: Actually, $2$ is the degree of the left-hand-side $(y')^2-2xy'+x^2$.  Whether it can be factored is not considered in defining the degree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Degree is concept used with (poly)nomial equations/expressions.
If i treat $y'$ as another variable, such as $p$, then your eqation transforms into:
$$p^2-2xp+x^2=0$$
This is a multivariate eqation because it has more than one variable.
If we treat either $p$ or $x$ as the coefficients of the univariate polynomial of the other variable $x$ or $p$ then we have second-degree polynomials.
If we treat it as a proper multivariate polynomial, then it is also a second-degree polynomial, a homogenous one as the sum of the exponents of each variable in each term is two ($p^2\rightarrow2,xp\rightarrow1+1=2,x^2\rightarrow2)$.

Asking what's the degree of a polynomail doesn't really make sense, unless we specify in what sense.
With differential equations we rather talk about the order of it, which can be thought as the analogue of a degree.
The degree of a differential eqation is the order of the highest derivative in an eqation.
For example
$$y''+(y')^3-7y-x^5=0$$ is a second-degree eqation because the highest derivative we have is the second. The $(y')^3$ causes it to be non-linear but that's not the highest order and the $x^5$ is not even in $y$-s, which we care about.

As @Shiva said, your eqation is a first-order eqation. Algebraically manipulating it generally shouldn't change this quantity.